# What size of image is better to have for the TensorFlow Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I want to know when training my own image dataset by using a pre-trained model (e.g: **ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco**, **ssd_inception_v2_coco**, **faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco**, **...**) what image size is better to resize the images before starting creating TF record and training?

I am asking this because when I collecting images it has different size, some are very large (`1920x1080`, `...`), but I don't know if it is good or not to resize the images.

And also does it depends or not on the model I want to choose? If does, then what is the better size for every model?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Most (all?) of the models you reference are trained on 224 x 224 size images. For best performance, you will need to scale your images to that size. Unless you are detecting tiny objects, resizing larger size images to smaller size required for the models does not seem to impact performance.

If your desired objects are tiny and you are afraid of losing resolution, you can crop the original image into smaller sections for training and then re-assemble. This will be time consuming but can work. My repo on detecting PSV symbols on diagrams uses this technique: https://github.com/siddiqaa/psvcounter

Comment: 224x224 maybe very small, because we alose need to label the images, resize the image to such small size will cause the image to lose a lot of data and labeling process cannot be very well, but I don't know if I am right?

Comment: You can label at full-size and then scale both the bounding boxes (label) and images. No way to tell without trying. The other option if you objects are really small is to crop the larger images into smaller sizes and then feed the cropped sections into the NN one at a time and re-assemble. This will add processing time - see my repo here for guidance: https://github.com/siddiqaa/psvcounter

Comment: Hmmm, this needs to try. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't get a better answer - mark this one so others will know. There's already a similar question on SO but the answer was not voted or accepted.

Comment: OK, first I need to try the concept, after if the result was good, then come back and share the result here and mark.

Comment: What about changing the image size parameters in the model description from 224x224 to very large like 6000x4000 in the case of large satellite images.  Is it possible to retrain after changing image size from model checkpoint or do you have to start from scratch?